# font kerning differs in chrome and firefox even after using the reset.css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

this is something new to me. My html font renders differently in chrome and firefox even after  using the reset.css. This is my url

http://spheretekk.com/form1/fct14-grpap-marseille-Paris.html

If you see in firefox the title being overlapped by the right hand side start balloon

[image]

Comment: You show give some description of the differences. They are not strikingly obvious on first look, are they?

Comment: Don’t ever expect fonts to be rendered identically on/in different devices, systems and browsers. Best solution for your problem here would IMHO be that you give the headline a specific width, so that the text can not go under the button no matter what, and will break into another line if necessary.

Comment: It’s not your font (Noto Serif) that renders differently, it’s the browsers’ default fonts. Most computers do not have Noto Serif, and there is no `@font-face` that would make it a downloadable font (web font).

Comment: Thanks a lot.. though i used a conditional css  <style type='text/css'>
/*Firefox*/

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
 h2.title2 {
margin-right:25px;
}
}
</style>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not kerning, it’s differing implementations of `font-variant: small-caps`.

Common default fonts used by browsers (or the Noto Serif font for that matter) do not contain genuine small caps, i.e. small cap glyphs designed by a typographer. Even if they did, current browsers are unable to use them to implement the CSS setting. Instead, they generate fake small caps by replacing a lowercase letter by the corresponding uppercase letter in reduced size. This is typographically all wrong – the stroke widths become too small, and uppercase letters thus differ in style from the fake small-caps (look bolder than they).

Apparently, browsers do the size reduction slightly differently.

You can work around this by removing `small-caps` and doing the font reduction yourself, e.g. writing

```
C<small>ULINARY</small> F<small>RENCH</small> W<small>ATERWAYS</small>
```

and setting e.g.

```
small { font-size: 70% }
```

in CSS (tune the percentage to your liking). It will still be typographically awful, but at least as similar across browsers as you can get – provided that you either use Noto Serif as a downloadable font or put some widely available font(s) like Times New Roman before or in place of `serif` in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers tend to vary in their interpretation of font size. Personally I tend to set the body font size to 62.4%, by doing this you can then use ems to set the font size for individual elements when, for example, 1.4em = 14px, 1.8em = 18px, etc. This might work for you.

Having said all this... the discrepancy is really tiny... is it really worth all the hassle?? There are more important things in life :)